# Having troubles with json array

Tags: java, android, eclipse, json

first of all thanks for taking the time to look at my problem, I am new at android development and I am having a problem with a array coming from a PHP server encoded on JSON, I try to look for an answer but all the examples of JSON use the field name to decode the array, mine does not have field names.

This is an example of the array that can be of many strings:

```
[["104733","\u5e38\u4e16\u7530 \u9752","images\/myphoto\/104733_20120711101030_sq_s.jpg","062556","2012\/11\/21","test20121121-2","Test2\n\u643a\u5e2f\u304b\u3089","11.11","333.33","555.55","77.77","22:22:22","20:44:44","19:07:06","17:29:28",0," ","0"," "," ","61116",0," "]
,["104733","\u5e38\u4e16\u7530 \u9752","images\/myphoto\/104733_20120711101030_sq_s.jpg","062555","2012\/11\/21","test20121121","Test\n\u643a\u5e2f\u304b\u3089","11.11","333.33","555.55","77.77","22:22:22","20:44:44","19:07:06","17:29:28",0," ","0"," "," ","61117",0," "]]
```

Basically where say \u643a\u5e2f\u304b\u3089 are characters in japanese for 携帯から.

I manage to separate the fields manually using this kind of loop but still getting the names in the coded format.

```
                       for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
            //Separate the string in to the different groups
            endIdx = strcline.indexOf("]", startIdx)+1;
            String temp = strcline.substring(startIdx, endIdx);

            //Get the user id from the string temp
            startIdx2 = 2;
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String userId = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.v("temp", userId);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the user name
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String userName = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.w("temp", userName);
            //String userName2 = new String(userName.getBytes(), "UTF-8");

            //Log.d("fullurl", userName2);
            //Log.w("temp", String.valueOf(userName2));
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the user photo url
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String userPhoto = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", userPhoto);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the training id
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String trainingId = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", trainingId);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the diary's date
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String diaryDate = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", diaryDate);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the Diary's title
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String diaryTitle = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", diaryTitle);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the diary's content
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String diaryContent = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", diaryContent);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the swim distance
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String swimDistance = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", swimDistance);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the bike distance
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String bikeDistance = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", bikeDistance);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the run distance
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String runDistance = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", runDistance);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the other distance
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String otherDistance = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", otherDistance);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the swim time
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String swimTime = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", swimTime);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the bike time
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String bikeTime = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", bikeTime);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the run time
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String runTime = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", runTime);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the other time
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String otherTime = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", otherTime);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 2;

            //Get the number of photos
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2);
            String numPhotos = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", numPhotos);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 2;

            //Get the string for the Photos
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String stringPhotos = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", stringPhotos);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the like flag
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String likeFlg = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", likeFlg);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the name of friend who liked
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String friendLiked = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", friendLiked);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the string for the likes
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String stringLike = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", stringLike);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 3;

            //Get the id for this array
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2) - 1;
            String arrayId = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", arrayId);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 2;

            //Get the number of comments
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf(",", startIdx2);
            String numberComments = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.d("temp", numberComments);
            startIdx2 = endIdx2 + 2;

            //Get the string for the comments
            endIdx2 = temp.indexOf("]", startIdx2) - 1;
            String stringComments = temp.substring(startIdx2, endIdx2);
            Log.e("temp", stringComments);

            startIdx = endIdx + 1;

            arrayTemp[i] = temp;
            Log.w("LogStr", temp);
        }
```

Comment: Why not use a library for parsing the json such as jackson, Gson, etc?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use gson, but it says that it requires name field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is an array of arrays of Strings, that is why you do not have field names. They are only present in objects.

Parsing json with String operations is a pain. You should have a look at the classes in the `org.json` package and start parsing with a `JSONArray` here.

```
JSONArray a1 = new JSONArray(json);
for (int i = 0; i < a1.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray a2 = a1.getJSONArray(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < a2.length(); j++) {
    String s1 = a2.getString(j);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean with the array been an array of arrays of string, however as I mention before I'm still quite new to android and java development, could be a bit more explicit please.

Comment: Thanks @brillenheini, I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm sure I am doing something very stupid but I'm getting an infinite loop until it crashes.

Comment: I'm sorry @brillenheini indeed I was doing something very stupid, just placed the int i instead of the j, (looks like the cold I catch is worst than I excpected. it looks like is working

Comment: now I know I am asking too much, but how can I give the value of each field to its own field? id = 104733, name = user name, etc?

Comment: @David You can omit the inner loop and just do `id = a2.getString(0)` and so on.